# Equivalent of Linux 'zip -FF' in Python

Tags: python, zip

I have a python application that works with .zip files. Occasionally this application will fail with error `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`

In spot checking the failed files, I've found that a working zip file can be created using the `zip -FF` Linux command.

The issue is that the application works with the files in memory via BytesIO. I would prefer to avoid having to write them to disk in order to run the Linux command.

Is there any python module which implements the equivalent of `zip -FF` that I can use on these files in memory?

Comment: You could use `subprocess.Popen` with the command `zip -FF` but instead of running on a file, you run on the content in memory, by using the `Popen.communicate()` function. Did you try ?

Comment: "working" - if you need FF, then the end of the file is probably missing (including an unknown amount of the contents). You definitely should not quietly accept such archives.

Comment: If this is happening frequently, it sounds like you're trying to process a zip file that's still being written. You should come up with a way to detect when the file is complete before you process it. As @teapot418 says, silently ignoring the error is a bad workaround.

Comment: Where are these failed files coming from? You need to get them fixed at the source. You should not be trusting "fixed" zip files. It may be as simple as the writer not properly closing the zip file when done writing entries.